# Why might something execute in node but not in the REPL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, emscripten, asm.js

I have the following script:

```
const lib = require('./lib.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const graph = fs.readFileSync('../js-working-dir/add_graph.pb', 'utf8');
const sess = new lib.Session(graph);
const results = sess.run({"a": 5, "b": 6}, ["o"]);
console.log(results[0]);
```

*(For context `lib.js` is a compiled emscripten module; it is fairly big, approximately 40MB, otherwise I would upload it.)*

When I execute this script in node, it works fine. However when I execute it in the REPL (same working directory and everything) my code hangs on `const sess = new lib.Session(graph);`.

**Any ideas of why this might be the case? Does Emscripten treat the REPL and node execution differently? Is there a way I can debug where it is getting stuck?**

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks so much,

Comment: I would prefer not to upload the file if someone has an idea off hand (just because it is relatively large), but if no one has any ideas within a day or so I'll find a way...

Comment: Don't know what would create the difference - would it be difficult to narrow it down by adding logs in the lib.js when Session is invoked?

Comment: Can try that now and report back, just such a strange bug I figured I had to be missing something obvious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem found, appears to be a bug in urandom...

https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/4905